# performing multiple actions on one button in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a wizard in java swing programatically.

On the wizard pane  I have a next button and it has to perform multiple actions according to which panel is displayed on the wizard.

Is it possible to use java command pattern? may I know how?
thanks in advance.

the code i used for the wizard is

```
this.mainPanel.add(fileSelectionPane,"SELECT FILE");
this.mainPanel.add(sqlConnectionPane,"SQL CONNECTION");           
this.mainPanel.add(devicePane,"PARSER");    
this.mainPanel.add(detailsPane,"DISPLAY");      
thisLayout.show(this.mainPanel,"SELECT FILE");    
this.finishButton.setEnabled(false);
this.backButton.setEnabled(false);
if(newValue==1)    {     
    this.thisLayout.show(this.mainPanel, "SQL CONNECTION");   
    this.nextButton.setEnabled(true);    
    this.nextButton.setText("Connect..");  
    this.cancelButton.setEnabled(true);    
    this.backButton.setEnabled(true);
}  

if(newValue==2)    {    
    this.thisLayout.show(this.mainPanel, "PARSER");  
    this.nextButton.setEnabled(true);    
    this.nextButton.setText("Parse..");  
    this.cancelButton.setEnabled(true);    
    this.backButton.setEnabled(true);    
}
```

i want the next button to perform specific actions on SELECT FILE and SQL CONNECTION.

is it possible to use command patterns?

Comment: Isn't it more reasonable to allow the current "panel" to decide what actions need to be taken rather then the "next" button??

Comment: Please update your question iso posting code in comments. And take a look at [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) if you want to create a wizard using Swing

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so, You add action listeners to buttons. These action listeners do something when an event occurs.

You want to change the functionality of the button depending on which panel is being displayed? Why not set a instance variable which reflects the state of the Wizard?

For example (roughly),

int state = 0; // home panel

change panel to help page, event listener is fire, set 'state' to 1. You are now tracking which panel is being displayed.

Now, in your original problem, when the button (the one you want multiple functionality with) fires, you can choose the action it will take based on the 'state' var.

Answer (score 1):

1. have look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
2. those cards put to the [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) (`JDialog` has preimplemented by default [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)) to the CENTER area
3. create a new [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and place there [JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
4. `JPanel` with `JButtons` put to the `SOUTH` area
5. search here, on this forum, there are a few excelent examples for wizard or image previue based on `CardLayout`

Answer (score 1):

try the following code for button:

```
JButton btn1;
btn1= new javax.swing.JButton();
btn1.setToolTipText("Submit");
btn1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btn1.setBorderPainted(false);
btn1.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
btn1.addActionListener(this);
btn1.setIcon(this.getIcons()[21]);
add(btn1); // add to Jpanel
btn1.setBounds(250,10, 12, 12);

public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Object obj = evt.getSource();
   if (obj == btn1) {
      // your function on on click of button
      return;
   }
```